# PHP-FPM child processes are created and not going away

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have a ubuntu 15.04 server with 160GB of RAM and 40 cpu cores. Nginx is the web server and varnish is used for the cache. The site is in wordpress with very high traffic on weekdays. The `www.conf` is:

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = 127.0.0.1:7654
listen.backlog = 65535
listen.owner = www-data
listen.owner = www-data

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 1000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.max_requests = 500

chdir = /
```

I am using Monit for the monitoring.

In monit, it can be seen that php **child processes** are being created in dramatic manner. It tends to increase and **stops at pm.max_children** value. Not a single child-process is killed or respwaned and then the site becomes unresponsive. Only reloading or restarting php5-fpm make the site in the working state, i.e. the processes need to kill manually. 
Why the processes are not respawned automatically? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's not duplicate because I am not having that error and the problem still remain everytime I increase the value of pm.max-children.

Comment: hmm.. said "may be" :)  looks like problem with script to me.. can be anything basically. Can't speculate without seeing your actual script.

Comment: I also think that it's good for serverfault. Is there any simple way to migrate this question to serverfault?

Comment: flag it for a mod. He will do it if he feels.

Comment: Okay I will update my question with the whole script.